# Implementation guid or Tutorials to implement Sitecore E-commerce connector with external commerce system

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-commerce-server

I am struglling to start implementation or development for sitecore ecommerce connector. I tried to google to find some tutorials but there is not much information available. I have successfully install sitecore and commerce connector but i don't know how to start developing product and other services to sync product data. Please provide some links.

Answer (score 1):

On this youtube channel you will find a demo video how to start with commerce connect. It is connected to a NopCommerce website.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JECKXgAOAZU

You can find also informations on github account :

https://github.com/Sitecore/Commerce-Connect-StarterKit/tree/release/8.2.281/master

This will be your starting point to choose correct version.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Commerce_Connect.aspx

I hope it helps you.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. I tried all these things. There are a lot of issues with commerce connector starter kit if you will try to integrate the plugins with nopCommerce it will generates error, especially with inventory and product plugins. I spend 2 to 3 days to resolve those issues but it’s very difficult because when you solve one issue by adding latest assemblies other functionalities will start breaking. It seems you have good exp. in Sitecore, I would request you kindly try it and please provide some help to resolve those issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore provides "Commerce Connect" to connect to external system. Commerce Connect is an integration layer between a front-end web shop solution and a back-end e-commerce system

You can get more information on http://www.sitecore.net/en/products/sitecore-experience-platform/cross-channel-delivery/commerce